# error with rowSums usng column names

Tags: r

I am trying to segment Census data from fairly deaggregated data (e.g. age variables in 5-yr groups), & creating summary variables based on aggregation (e.g. all males 18+ per county). My solution is rowSums, e.g. `county$MalesOver18 <- rowSums(county[,c(68:87)])`, where vars 68-87 sum to males 18+ -- works fine. However, with 500 variables it is not efficient to count out the order of my start/end columns.

But when I use my preferred solution, column names for rowSums (e.g. `rowSums(county[,c(H76007:H76025)]`, where H vars = field names), I get one of 2 msg errors:

run w/ col names in quotes:  `Error in "H76007":"H76025" : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In`[.data.frame`(county, , c("H76007":"H76025")) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In`[.data.frame`(county, , c("H76007":"H76025")) :
  NAs introduced by coercion`

run w/ col names not in quotes: `Error in`[.data.frame`(county, , c(H76007:H76025)) : 
  object 'H76007' not found`

I have tried using the na.rm command & setting my variables as numeric -- although they are already integers -- and all to no result.

any guidance? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` cannot be used for character type. Try to first obtain the index:

```
rowSums(county[,(which(names(county)=='H76007'):which(names(county)=='H76025'))])
```

Comment: Is there a way to include multiple groups of columns, such as `rowSums(county[,(which(names(county)=='H76007'):which(names(county)=='H76025'))]), which(names(county) == 'H9E007'):which(names(county) == 'H9E025'))`. I know that the "," is not the correct way to do this.

Comment: Yes, use `c()` to concatenate the vectors. So `,` is fine, but enclose them within `c()`

Answer (score 3):

When indexing data.frames by the column names, you can't use the `:` operator. When you do this with numeric values, it creates a sequence:

```
> 2:5
[1] 2 3 4 5
```

However, that doesn't work with character data which is what you were seeing:

```
> "foo":"bar"
Error in "foo":"bar" : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
...
```

So, what to do? I can think of two options:

1. Use `grepl` and some regex magic to identify the column names that you want to return. Here's a trivial example with the `mtcars` data:

#

```
colsToOperateOn <- grepl("mpg|cyl", colnames(mtcars))
> head(mtcars[, colsToOperateOn], 2)
              mpg cyl
  Mazda RX4      21   6
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6
```

You would need to write however complicated of a regex as necessary to get the columns you want.

1. Use `which` to identify the index of the starting and ending columns you want, and then turn those into a sequence:

#

```
start <- which(colnames(mtcars) == "mpg")
end <- which(colnames(mtcars) == "cyl")
> head(mtcars[, start:end], 2)
              mpg cyl
Mazda RX4      21   6
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6
```

This may be a poor example since `mpg` and `cyl` are right next to one another, but it should prove the point.